# Plotting on a complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm very confused how you would plot the relationship $|z-4| \leq |z|$.  I tried to change it in form which could become $-|z|\leq|z-4|\leq|z|$ and I guess the same can be done for z-4.  But I don't get really get how I can plot it.  Can I get some help here?

Comment: Hint: what does `|z - 4|` represent geometrically?  Can you think of it as some sort of distance?  What about `|z|`?  Alternative hint: if you want to work purely algebraically, start by squaring both sides.

Comment: well |z-4| is basically a circle centered at 4 without any boundary and if it is bounded by |z|, a circle centered at 0  then is what we're plotting a circle with center 4 and radius 4?

Comment: $|z-4| = 3$ would be the equation of a circle, for example. But $|z-4|$ is a number, not an equation, so it can't represent a circle on its own.

Comment: @cambelot Wrong, $|z-4|$ is **not** a circle, it is a distance of point $z$ from point $4$.

Answer (score 2):

If you read "$|z-4| \le |z|$" out loud, it should sound like:

> "The distance from $z$ to $4$ is less than or equal to the distance from $z$ to $0$."

Once you have done that, the answer should be almost obvious.

Comment: so using this logic its basically any x value greater than or equal to 2 right?

Comment: @cambelot "Any $x$-value" can be improved. I would say "all $z$, such that $\operatorname{Re} z \ge 2$" instead. But it looks like the question was to *plot* the solution: you want to indicate the corresponding half-plane in your figure.

Comment: okay and this would be just the block of right of 2, right?  And this would not be a domain (a subset on complex plane that is open and connected)

Answer (score 0):

The locus described in the question asks for all complex numbers are all about circles. For example, consider (for real $a$)
\begin{eqnarray}
|z-a| &=& \sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+y^{2}} \\
\end{eqnarray}
So in the simpler case for (say) $|z-a|=2$,
\begin{eqnarray}
|z-a| &=& 2 \\
      &=& \sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
4           &=& \sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+y^{2}} \\
\implies 16 &=& (x-a)^{2} + y^{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Which is the circle with radius $4$, centre $(a, 0)$. You can then apply this approach to your questions.